# Tor hidden services not working?

Tags: onion-services

So I recently setup tor on a VPS with the hope of creating a hidden service, the issue being I cannot get the hidden service to start.

[Link to Torrc](http://pastebin.com/Kd2sggwG)

The issue is that it is not creating the folder in which it is to generate the Private key and .onion.
This is where my issue lies. I cannot seem to find a SINGLE similar matter. I do assume I've screwed up somewhere but I just can't find it.

P.S. Yes it's being run as root.

Comment: is /usr/local/etc/tor/hidden_service/ owned, readable and writable by the user that starts the Tor process?

Comment: What does it say in your Tor log?
There should be a hint there on what is going wrong.
Please check that before anything else.

Comment: I had an issue finding the logs on debian, could you give me the path that it defaults to.
About the question of permissions, yes.

Comment: @user2738843 default log location on debian /var/log/tor/log

Comment: @user2738843 Line 36 in your pasted `torrc` has a line starting with `Log`. Just uncomment it and restart Tor. So Tor will write logging info into that file.